# Debugging iOS-Xamarin bridge?

Tags: ios, xamarin

I converted my project from classic to unified, and my api definition file doesn't seem to bridge a library correctly for me any more - it looks like the first call I'm wrapping fails because it's not found (at least that's how I'm interpreting this stack trace):

```
22  FareInspector                 0x00392931 mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:2377)
23  FareInspector                 0x0039b165 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (mini-runtime.c:2875)
24  libsystem_platform.dylib      0x1e62326d _sigtramp + 25
25  libobjc.A.dylib               0x1e036703 lookUpImpOrForward + 159
26  libobjc.A.dylib               0x1e036703 lookUpImpOrForward + 159
27  libobjc.A.dylib               0x1e036661 _class_lookupMethodAndLoadCache3 + 27
28  libobjc.A.dylib               0x1e03c96f _objc_msgSend_uncached + 15
29  FareInspector                 0x0002df2b -[xValidator informUIRegardingReadyState] (xValidator.m:458)
```

This is the ApiDefinition that isn't working:

```
namespace XValidator {
    [BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
    [Model]
    [Protocol]
    public partial interface ValidatorDelegate {
        [Export("validatorReadyToUse:")]
        void ValidatorReadyToUse(string sState);
    }
```

And the method signature that should get called:
namespace FareInspector {

```
public class ValidatorDelegateHandler : ValidatorDelegate {
    public override void ValidatorReadyToUse(string sState) {
```

I verified that the XValidator library I'm wrapping hasn't changed its signature for this method - it is still passing a single NSString parameter for validatorReadyToUse.

Am I interpreting this correctly? Is there an additional classic to unified conversion step I'm missing? Or what else can I do to figure out why this is failing?

Comment: It looks like the last Obj-C message sent was: `[xValidator informUIRegardingReadyState]` Have you gone over this guide? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/unified/update-binding/

Comment: @jgoldberger thank you, I went through that doc again, but I'm still having trouble - not sure what I missed. Any idea how to debug this or things I can try to fix it?